# how to turn on port b pins in arduino assembly atmega328

Tags: assembly, arduino, location, led

im new to arduino assembly basicly, the code below turns on and off port b pin 5(led13) on arduino atmega328

```
// turn onboard LED on 
// 
" ldi r18,0x20 ; bit 5 (pin 13) = high \n" 
" out 5,r18 ; output to port B \n" 
// turn onboard LED off 
// 
" ldi r18,0x00 ; value for all LEDs off \n" 
" out 5,r18 ; output to port B \n"
```

so how can i turn on and off port b pin 4(led12) 3(11)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By using bits 4 (0x10) and 3 (0x08) instead.

Comment: // turn onboard LED on
    //   
    "               ldi  r18,0x10    ; bit 4 (pin 12) = high  \n"
    "               out  5,r18               ; output to port B       \n"
      // turn onboard LED on
    //   
    "               ldi  r18,0x08            ; bit 3 (pin 11) = high  \n"
    "               out  5,r18               ; output to port B       \n"
 
is that right for pin12 and 11?